# Algorithm for generating polygons of land allocation within a defined boundary

Tags: javascript, typescript, computational-geometry

We are looking for a solution to create novel land allocations of an existing area into a subset of polygons for each allocation within the existing space.

A high level overview of the requirements are:

- The boundary of the land to be allocated will be defined as a GeoJSON feature set and may be made up of a number of polygons.
- Each allocations within the boundary are to be made to an account and will be provided in m². Sizes of the account allocations may range in size from 1 to several 1000's m².
- Visually we would prefer for the allocations to be made in convex polygons with a resulting shape that is similar to a voronoi diagram.  Given that the boundaries may be concave polygons it will be acceptable for an area polygon allocated on a boundary to be concave.
- Over time the land allocated to different accounts will change.  Existing accounts will allocate more land and new accounts will be allocated until the whole boundary space is eventually filled. Ideally we should be able to plot a timeseries of these allocations and see individual allocations grow over time.  Ideally we would try to keep an allocation in the same general area of the project over time, however we accept that things need to move to make room.
- Given that we are dealing with irregular polygons we understand that an exact area is not going to be possible in all cases so we would be happy if the actual area of the allocated polygon is within 1% of the actual allocation.
- Each boundary may end up with 10's of thousands of allocations and the creation of an area allocation polygon needs to be able to be executed as quickly as possible.
- Ideally we should be able to return a change to an existing polygon, or the shape of a new polygon in less than 500ms. Therefore the solution needs to be efficient and solvable in P time.

So far we have tried a brute force approach (using turf.js) starting with allocating the first area to be assigned by picking a random point along the boundary and generating a polygon and shifting the points until the area of the polygon matches the area required. Then removing that polygon from the original boundary and trying with the next polygon to allocate.

There are a number of issues with this approach including the challenge of ensuring the generated polygons are meeting the correct shape and not overlapping with one another.  Dealing with concave areas in the boundary have also proved a bit tricky.  Also the time to calculate thousands of allocations is a concern.

We have also considered setting seed points to use to generate polygons using the d3 Voronoi library. However Voronoi diagrams are not really designed for generating polygons with a specific area and shifting the seed points around to meet the exact size seems like an even harder problem.

We are hoping someone may be able to point us to an algorithm or help us with an approach that may help us solve this challenge.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please include the code you want to get help with. It's impossible for us to improve code we can't see, and we're not a code-writing service. That way, you're much more likely to get the answers you need.

Comment: Thanks for the welcome. I am not specifically looking for help with the code, I'm more than capable of tackling the code.  I'm really hoping to get some guidance on approaches that we could take to solve the problem.  Ideally if there are any known computational geometry algorithms that we might be able to consider.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

An easy approach would be a variant of [Lloyd's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lloyd%27s_algorithm), which uses iterative relaxation to position `n` points in a bounded area such that all points' Voronoi cells have roughly equal areas.

The central idea behind Lloyd's algorithm is that when you move a Voronoi cell's generating point towards the cell's centroid, its area tends to increase if it's too small. So in each iteration of Lloyd's algorithm you move each generator towards the corresponding centroid; and then in the next iteration the areas are more equal.

In this case, you should move the generator some *fraction* of the way towards its centroid, proportional to the ratio between its desired area and its current area. (As with regular Lloyd's, you can apply an additional constant multiplier to accelerate convergence).

The result will be a bounded Voronoi diagram, so all allocations will be convex. Given a reasonably good geometry package, I would expect good convergence with thousands of points to take only a few milliseconds.